# PHP Arrays diff

Tags: arrays, diff

Having 
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$age2 = array("Peter"=>"Peter", "Ben"=>"Ben");

I want an output like:
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37"); // without Joe and with same index

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do but $age2 array doesn't really seem, well.. useful? If you just want to remove Joe from array  use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: Removing Joe is based of it doesn't exists in $age2 array, tried to simplify it, but the actual data is more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to compare $age1 and $age2 and remove from $age1 any entry that isn't in $age2? Use [array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) like so:

```
$missingElements = array_diff_key($age2, $age1);

foreach($missingElements as $element) { // For each element NOT in both arrays
    $index = $age1.indexOf($element);

    unset($age1[$index]);
}

var_dump($age1); // Print on screen
```

This PHP function compares the **key** of 2 arrays and returns the difference. So we loop over each element returned by the function and remove them from $age1;

Comment: Sounds good, and if it is a value not the index? Can i just use array_diff?

Comment: @user1143217 yes you can but from what you gave me the only concurrent value between the 2 is the key, so I compare them by that but you can use the same script to compare arrays by value.

Comment: Why I'm getting:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)  ??

Comment: @user1143217 . Oops, sorry Javascript habit. Change $age1.unset() to just unset()